# Is the Fullscreen API supported in Android Browser and iOS Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, google-chrome

I have a full-page React application. By this, I mean that the width and height of the application take up the width and height of the browser viewport.

I would like to hide the address bar in Android Browser or iOS Chrome. This is very valuable space for a full-page data visualization application. In landscape orientation on an iPhone XS, for instance, the address bar takes up approximately 14% of the screen's vertical space.

That's a lot of real estate for a piece of UI that is not immediately useful, which I'd like to hide away, where I can.

I attempted to use the [Google Web developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#fake_it_auto-hide_the_address_bar) to hide the address bar via a non-vendor specific function, e.g.:

```
toggleFullScreen = () => {
  var doc = window.document;
  var docEl = doc.documentElement;

  var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
  var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

  if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
    requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
  }
  else {
    cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
  }
}
```

This results in an error thrown at the call `requestFullScreen.call(docEl)`, where `docEl` does not exist.

I also tried the following in `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 1000);
}
```

This second approach did not work, perhaps because of the viewport dimensions of my application. It does not yield any errors. However, increasing the height in the application CSS did not work, either.

The third approach I tried was to add a `meta` tag in the application:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This appeared not to do anything.

As last ditch attempts, I tested https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/ on iOS Chrome on my iPhone, but its demo page suggests that the Fullscreen API is not supported. I also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/toggle-fullscreen and similar NPM-sourced packages to access the Fullscreen API. None of them seemed to work and most seemed to issue errors similar to those I ran into with the `toggleFullScreen` method described above.

Is there a correct, working method to hide the address bar via a pure JavaScript call, which requires no user interaction, or is the Fullscreen API simply not supported on Android Browser / iOS Chrome browsers?

Comment: Did they work on other devices?

Comment: Other than the device simulator built into desktop Chrome, I have an iOS device to test on.

Comment: Are you trying to use it on page load? It also might be a browser-specific problem. Try using MDN and Caniuse.com to see if the Fullscreen API is supported.

Comment: I am trying to use this method when the React component/application is mounted, with adjustments to the timeout to allow the DOM to be rendered.

Comment: Caniuse.com says that the Fullscreen API is supported, but vendor-agnostic calls to that API yield errors. I'm not sure which source to trust, except that it doesn't appear to work in reality.

Comment: What about MDN?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216586/discussion-between-alex-reynolds-and-galaxycat105).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question 'Is there a correct, working method to hide the address bar via a pure JavaScript call, which requires no user interaction' is, acccording to the MDN webdocs (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen), no. It states explicitly that it will fail when it is not called from a ui interaction or a device orientation change.

If one of the browsers that you mention does succeed in going fullscreen (by using requestFullScreen)in another situation, it is an implementation error and should not be relied on to persist in future versions.

Answer (score 3):

### Fullscreen is a feature the user must request.

This is an intentional choice from the Chrome team and any browser vendor that supports the Fullscreen API. So trying to call that onLoad isn't going to work. You might be able to find some React libraries to make your life easier but you'll need to add a button at the very least.

If you're going to add a "fullscreen" button, you might want to consider going a step further... and make the app "installable".

### Other option: PWA

Why not create a Progressive Web App? If you're expecting to have a full-screen implementation that seems to be exactly the experience PWAs were created to address.

Additionally, with a PWA you get an app like icon on the screen, background updates, push notifications, and much more. Here's the [Google Developer's overview](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/getting-started-pwa). PWAs work in Chrome, FF, IE, Edge, and mostly in Safari (90% or so as of this writing).

To create a PWA you'll need to [define a web manifest file](https://web.dev/add-manifest/). This allows you to set icons, modify the presentation, and so on.

### PWAs with JS Frameworks

There are helper libraries for all the major JS frameworks to make it easier to build a PWA. Since you're using React this [is the best overview I've seen](https://alligator.io/react/react-progressive-web-apps/).

That said, you really only need a manifest file and to register a service worker to get started.

- [Google PWA](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) help (codelabs, docs, etc)
- [React PWA Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/)
- Angular official [PWA guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)
- Vue CLI [PWA Plugin](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a simple tool to show Italy covid-19 data charts; you can test it following [this link](https://covid-19.trinityteam.it/coronavirus/grafico/andamento/0/0/e/cdhasibpne) than pressing *surface* link. You can view the [repository](https://github.com/iccicci/covid19) to check it by yourself. Anyway the core is [here](https://github.com/iccicci/covid19/blob/master/client/src/Charts.js#L192).

A short briefing: to open full screen (where `root` is the default id for root DIV in React.js)

```
document.getElementById("root").requestFullscreen({ navigationUI: "hide" });
```

to close full screen:

```
if(document.fullscreenElement) document.exitFullscreen();
```

I tested this both on IOS and Android.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Within iOS Chrome, this yields the following error/exception: `TypeError: document.getElementById("root").requestFullscreen is not a function.` Within the Chrome mobile device simulator viewport, I see the following error/exception: `Unhandled Exception (TypeError): fullscreen error`.

Comment: Loading your linked site on iOS Chrome and clicking "surface" does not hide the address bar (it does not switch the browser to a fullscreen mode).

Comment: Sorry @AlexReynolds , actually I didn't tested it on iOS Chrome

Comment: Looking around @AlexReynolds it really seems it's not support yet, but being this the standard I suggest you to go on with your app instead focusing on this. They'll integrate it soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleFullscreen() {
  let elem = document.querySelector("div");// or other elements ...
  if (elem != null){
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      elem.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
        alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
      });
    } else {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```